# Visual Studio 2013 RC Installation Failure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I get a failure each time I try to install Visual Studio 2013 RC with ASP.NET MVC 4 already installed.

"Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime"
Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution required installing Visual Studio 2012 first and then 2013 RC.